# bash: 1 liner for selecting maximum files with total size limit

Tags: bash

In a directory I want to select maximum files with given total size and move them to a different directory. While listing files for selection, we need to sort them by name.

As an example, to make it clear, let us say the total size is 500MB with each file size being less than 500 MB.

**use case1:**

- a.bz2 200MB
- b.bz2 100MB
- c.bz2 300MB
- d.bz2 400MB

  Move a.bz2 and b.bz2 (total = 300MB) to directory ../selected (Because selecting 3rd file makes total size > 500MB)

**use case 2:**

- a.bz2 200MB
- b.bz2 200MB
- c.bz2 100MB
- d.bz2 400MB

  Move a.bz2 , b.bz2 and c.bz2 (total = 500MB) to directory ../selected

I know how to add size of each file but breaking the loop like in a C program requires me writing a script. Instead I want it in 1 liner using pipe ( | )

Comment: How are they sorted? Are the files always increasing in size? Are you trying to fit the max number of files? This seems half baked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this qualifies as a one-liner, but...

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -r -0 du -k |
  awk '{sum+=$1; if(sum>500000){exit}; print}' | cut -f2- | tr '\n' '\0' |
  xargs -r -0 mv -t ../selected
```

Comment: Using pipe ( | ) is absolutely a one liner

Comment: re: suggested edit, i've removed the mp3 part, and, afaik, `find` will deliver the results already in alphabetic order.